# How to create an object of a class present in one file from another file?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, constructor

I have two files `f1.py` & `f2.py`.

`f1.py` contains a class `C1`.

`f2.py` contains a class `C2` which inherits `C1`.

`C1` containts a constructor

```
def __init__ (self, user_name, user_password, db_name):

    self.user_name = user_name
    self.user_password = user_password
    self.db_name = db_name
```

& a method

```
 def m1(self):
    print user_name
```

I create an object in `f2`.

```
db3 = C2(user_name, user_password, db_name)
db3.conn_establish()
```

*Where, all the passed parameters are assigned some value*

If `C2` was present in the same file as `C1`. This would return no error. But, since `C2` is present in another file. I get an error

`NameError: global name 'user_name' is not defined`

To overcome which I have to change `m1` to: (just a workaround I found)

```
def m1(self):
    print self.user_name
```

Why did adding `self` work?

Answer (score 2):

The workaround you found is the right way to implement this.
The `self` argument is in fact the object reference you use to store and retrieve information from. If you don't use self, you are using a static variable and therefore you will have trouble if you create multiple instances of C1 (it's shared). Using self will force to check the instance's value (in either the class itself or from another class and/or file).

Comment: Sure. Added explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your function definition be:

```
 def m1(self):
    print self.user_name
```

Otherwise you are just printing some global value of `user_name`. I assume that such a value is present in f1.py which doesn't raise an error when both are present in the same file.